# Showing only Month and Year using the Data Segmentation visualization

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm using the Data Segmentation visualization in Power Bi to filter the page using a Date column, but it shows the whole date (Day, Month, Year) and I need to show only Month and Year, is there a way to filter out the day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new column in PowerBI desktop and use it.

Click on New Column in Home ribbon under Calculations section and enter like

```
MonthYear = Query1[CreatedDate].[Month] & "-" & Query1[CreatedDate].[Year]
```

Where `CreatedDate` is your current date field. Then you can use MonthYear column to filter.

Answer (score 0):

When adding the date into the Viz, right click on the field and you show be able to deselect the date items you do not want.